# Vue3 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a constructor

Tags: vue.js, constructor, syntax-error, vuejs3, flash-message

I've been having this issue for a few hours now, I'm trying to use vue-flash-message in my Vue app, but it keeps throwing this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: t is not a constructor'. I don't know where, or how this is happening. This is my main.js, and I'm not actually using  anywhere in the app yet. Would appreciate any form of help. Thank you

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import FlashMessage from '@smartweb/vue-flash-message';
import router from './router'
import store from './store'


const app = createApp(App);
app.use(FlashMessage);
app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: You're almost certainly using the lib for V2 with V3. Check its docs

Comment: vue-flash-message docs? I did, but it seems like it's not updated for vue3, because it still says to use Vue.use(FlashMessage);
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@smartweb/vue-flash-message

Comment: The first line is "⚡ 1.x.x-alpha version with Vue 3 support"

Comment: Oh wow, that flew over my head, thank you so much!

Comment: @EstusFlask I installed alpha-version but issue remains same. i got error that :  t3 is not a constructor

Comment: @VinodPatidar It's different, "t3" isn't the same as "t". It could mean a specific problem on your side. In case the problem persists, consider reasking with your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it could be version mismatch or else

Comment: @EstusFlask It is solved. I first installed old version but after that i update package to alpha. But error resolved using removing node_modules.